# Angular remove item from array not working

Tags: angularjs

This is probably a really easy and dumb error but for some reason I cannot remove an item from my Array that I create using an Ajax call. When I attempt to remove it I get this JS error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at h.$scope.remove (https://www.skykick.com/cmsctx/pv/mhintzke/culture/en-US/wg/725a2fa0-45ad-4…d7912fdf1/-/cms/getdoc/468aee97-0186-4241-b599-22e97438dcfa/pv.aspx:190:31)
    at bb.functionCall (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.17/angular.min.js:174:190)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.17/angular.min.js:191:167
    at h.$get.h.$eval (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.17/angular.min.js:111:121)
    at h.$get.h.$apply (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.17/angular.min.js:111:399)
    at HTMLTableRowElement.<anonymous> (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.17/angular.min.js:191:149)
    at HTMLTableRowElement.jQuery.event.dispatch (https://www.skykick.com/CMSScripts/jquery/jquery-core.js:3350:9)
    at HTMLTableRowElement.jQuery.event.add.elemData.handle.eventHandle (https://www.skykick.com/CMSScripts/jquery/jquery-core.js:2959:45)
```

Here is the code that causes it

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Test.ascx.cs" Inherits="CMSApp.CMSWebParts.SkyKick.PartnerPortalV2.Web_Planner.Test" %>

<div ng-app="Skykick" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div class="dashSection">
    <table id="tActivities" class="activityTable">
        <caption>Recently</caption>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="tbActivities">
            <tr ng-repeat="activity in activities" ng-click="remove(activity)">
                <td>{{ activity.Description }}</td>
                <td>{{ activity.Count }}</td>
                <td>{{ activity.CustomerName }}</td>
                <td>{{ activity.Date }}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>      
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.17/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.16/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var app = angular.module('Skykick', ['ngRoute'])

        app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {

        $scope.activities = new Array();

        $scope.remove = function (activity) {
            console.log(activity);
            $scope.activities.remove(activity);
        }



        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'https://www.skykick.com/WebApi/activity/recent/all'
        })
        .success(function (data, status) {
            $scope.activities = data.result.Activity;
        })
        .error(function (data, status) {
            console.log(data);
            alert("error");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have a built in .remove() property.

Comment: Oh wow, idk what I was thinking of then...

Comment: I just made this an answer. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript doesn't have a .remove() property so you'll have to refactor that to be more JavaScript'y. If activities is an Array, you could use .slice().